# Simulating OpenQASM 2.0 in Qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qasm

I'm just getting started with OpenQASM, but I'm feeling a bit confused. Is there a way to run the `.qasm` file I've written in Qiskit (i.e. in Python), or is OpenQasm only meant to be used within the IBM Quantum experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use qasm files to create a quantum circuit, two ways : via the methods `from_qasm_str` or `from_qasm_file` on a `QuantumCircuit`. See the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html?highlight=quantumcircuit#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file) about this. For example :

```
test = ''' OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[2];
creg c[2];

h q[0];
cx q[0],q[1];
'''
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_str(test)
```

This will create a `QuantumCircuit` from the str `test`. The same syntax work with the other method, just replace `test` with the path to the qasm file.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! That appears to have worked. I do have another question though. How would I go about getting the state from this QuantumCircuit object? I've tried `save_state()` but that throws an error. Do I have to then run this on a simulator (such as aer) to be able to retrieve the state? Maybe this ought to be a separate post

Comment: You can find the answer in this [tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/simulators/1_aer_provider.html#Saving-the-simulator-state) :)